# I can't override the adminhtml block and controller please suggest me missing parameter

Tags: magento2.2, blocks, adminhtml

I can't **override** the **adminhtml block** please suggest me missing parameter

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"></pre>
        <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals" type="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Totals" />

        <preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order" type="Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Order" />
</config>
```

Comment: Can you please add your custom block code here

Comment: i have added 
Block/Adminhtml/Totals.php file but not override

Comment: controller not override using perefence becuse Order class is abstract

Comment: Can you please add code of  Block/Adminhtml/Totals.php in your question?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion me but Block not override please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
```

Add this before the preference tag in place of -

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"></pre>
```

Also please confirm the di.xml file starts with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

If not worked, share the Block code with path

Comment: `Namespace\Modulename\etc\di.xml`
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals" type="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Totals" />    
</config>`

`Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Totals.php`

Comment: :D I mean you can edit the question